# Fill up column space in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I have been trying to cover this space by stretching down the graph, but have failed so far.

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-8 offset-lg-0">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <h6 class="text-primary fw-bold m-0">Total Returns %&nbsp;&nbsp;</h6>
                                <div class="dropdown no-arrow"><button class="btn btn-link btn-sm dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button"></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-end animated--fade-in">
                                        <p class="text-center dropdown-header">dropdown header:</p><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Another action</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Something else here</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div><canvas data-bss-chart="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;2016&quot;,&quot;2017&quot;,&quot;2018&quot;,&quot;2019&quot;,&quot;2020&quot;,&quot;2021&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Xross&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;64&quot;,&quot;152&quot;,&quot;211&quot;,&quot;246&quot;,&quot;416&quot;,&quot;513&quot;],&quot;fill&quot;:false},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;KSE-100&quot;,&quot;fill&quot;:false,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;15&quot;,&quot;17&quot;,&quot;18&quot;,&quot;-10&quot;,&quot;27&quot;,&quot;42&quot;],&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(238,0,0,0.81)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(238,0,0,0.81)&quot;,&quot;borderWidth&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;maintainAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;legend&quot;:{&quot;display&quot;:true,&quot;labels&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;},&quot;position&quot;:&quot;top&quot;},&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;bold&quot;},&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;xAxes&quot;:[{&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}],&quot;yAxes&quot;:[{&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}]}}}"></canvas></div>
                            <div class="card-body" style="transform: perspective(0px);height: 471;padding: 0;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4 offset-lg-0">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <h6 class="text-primary fw-bold m-0"><br><strong>Annual Returns % (1-Sept to 30-Aug)</strong><br><br></h6>
                                <div class="dropdown no-arrow"><button class="btn btn-link btn-sm dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button"></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-end animated--fade-in">
                                        <p class="text-center dropdown-header">dropdown header:</p><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Another action</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Something else here</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="text-start shadow" style="border-color: var(--bs-blue);color: var(--bs-blue);height: 471;"><canvas data-bss-chart="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;2016&quot;,&quot;2017&quot;,&quot;2018&quot;,&quot;2019&quot;,&quot;2020&quot;,&quot;2021&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Xross&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;64&quot;,&quot;88&quot;,&quot;59&quot;,&quot;35&quot;,&quot;170&quot;,&quot;97&quot;]},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;KSE-100&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(255,2,17,0.7)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(211,15,15,0.1)&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;15&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;-28&quot;,&quot;38&quot;,&quot;14&quot;]}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;maintainAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;legend&quot;:{&quot;display&quot;:true,&quot;labels&quot;:{&quot;bold&quot;:false,&quot;italic&quot;:false,&quot;fontColor&quot;:&quot;#666&quot;,&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;},&quot;position&quot;:&quot;bottom&quot;},&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;bold&quot;,&quot;display&quot;:false},&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;xAxes&quot;:[{&quot;gridLines&quot;:{&quot;drawBorder&quot;:true,&quot;drawTicks&quot;:true,&quot;borderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;zeroLineBorderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;drawOnChartArea&quot;:false},&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}],&quot;yAxes&quot;:[{&quot;gridLines&quot;:{&quot;drawBorder&quot;:true,&quot;drawTicks&quot;:true,&quot;borderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;zeroLineBorderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;drawOnChartArea&quot;:true},&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}]}}}"></canvas></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How do I increase the height of the graph to fill that space?

EDIT:

[image]

The column space goes down but not the graph. I would want the graph to stretch down as well.

Little help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, hope it helps :

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-8 offset-lg-0">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4 h-100">
          <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <h6 class="text-primary fw-bold m-0">Total Returns %&nbsp;&nbsp;</h6>
              <div class="dropdown no-arrow"><button class="btn btn-link btn-sm dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button"></button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-end animated--fade-in">
                      <p class="text-center dropdown-header">dropdown header:</p><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Something else here</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
          <canvas data-bss-chart="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;2016&quot;,&quot;2017&quot;,&quot;2018&quot;,&quot;2019&quot;,&quot;2020&quot;,&quot;2021&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Xross&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;64&quot;,&quot;152&quot;,&quot;211&quot;,&quot;246&quot;,&quot;416&quot;,&quot;513&quot;],&quot;fill&quot;:false},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;KSE-100&quot;,&quot;fill&quot;:false,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;15&quot;,&quot;17&quot;,&quot;18&quot;,&quot;-10&quot;,&quot;27&quot;,&quot;42&quot;],&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(238,0,0,0.81)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(238,0,0,0.81)&quot;,&quot;borderWidth&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;maintainAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;legend&quot;:{&quot;display&quot;:true,&quot;labels&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;},&quot;position&quot;:&quot;top&quot;},&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;bold&quot;},&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;xAxes&quot;:[{&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}],&quot;yAxes&quot;:[{&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}]}}}"></canvas></div>
          <div class="card-body" style="transform: perspective(0px);height: 471;padding: 0;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4 offset-lg-0">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4 h-100">
          <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <h6 class="text-primary fw-bold m-0"><br><strong>Annual Returns % (1-Sept to 30-Aug)</strong><br><br></h6>
              <div class="dropdown no-arrow"><button class="btn btn-link btn-sm dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button"></button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-end animated--fade-in">
                      <p class="text-center dropdown-header">dropdown header:</p><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">&nbsp;Something else here</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="text-start shadow h-100" style="border-color: var(--bs-blue);color: var(--bs-blue);height: 471;"><canvas data-bss-chart="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;2016&quot;,&quot;2017&quot;,&quot;2018&quot;,&quot;2019&quot;,&quot;2020&quot;,&quot;2021&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Xross&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;#4e73df&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;64&quot;,&quot;88&quot;,&quot;59&quot;,&quot;35&quot;,&quot;170&quot;,&quot;97&quot;]},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;KSE-100&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(255,2,17,0.7)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(211,15,15,0.1)&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[&quot;15&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;-28&quot;,&quot;38&quot;,&quot;14&quot;]}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;maintainAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;legend&quot;:{&quot;display&quot;:true,&quot;labels&quot;:{&quot;bold&quot;:false,&quot;italic&quot;:false,&quot;fontColor&quot;:&quot;#666&quot;,&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;},&quot;position&quot;:&quot;bottom&quot;},&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;bold&quot;,&quot;display&quot;:false},&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;xAxes&quot;:[{&quot;gridLines&quot;:{&quot;drawBorder&quot;:true,&quot;drawTicks&quot;:true,&quot;borderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;zeroLineBorderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;drawOnChartArea&quot;:false},&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}],&quot;yAxes&quot;:[{&quot;gridLines&quot;:{&quot;drawBorder&quot;:true,&quot;drawTicks&quot;:true,&quot;borderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;zeroLineBorderDash&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;drawOnChartArea&quot;:true},&quot;ticks&quot;:{&quot;fontStyle&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;beginAtZero&quot;:false}}]}}}"></canvas></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please check out the edit I made in the question

Comment: Hey, it still doesn't work. The card-body goes down the actual graph doesn't stretch.

Comment: The graph is being explicitly set to a height of 471. Unfortunately, since it's drawn in a canvas, it won't be able to have a completely natively fluid height. If the element won't be changing its height, you could just change the height of the chart.

Comment: @Struggling brat If you want to do that, you have to change the height of the graph

Comment: Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Applying `height: 100%` to your card will help.

`.card { height: 100%; }`

or you can add your desired 'class/id' and use css selector accordingly.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Can you pls check out the edit I made in the question.